# generate svg without foreignObject tag

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I am using [dom-to-image.js](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/blob/master/src/dom-to-image.js) plugin. The trouble is, it generates a `<foreignObject>` tag that taints the canvas. Here is the part that generates the svg.

```
function makeSvgDataUri(node, width, height) {
        return Promise.resolve(node)
            .then(function (node) {
                node.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
                return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
            })
            .then(util.escapeXhtml)
            .then(function (xhtml) {
                return '<foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">' + xhtml + '</foreignObject>';
            })
            .then(function (xhtml) {
                return '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' +
                    xhtml + '</svg>';
            })
            .then(function (svg) {
                return 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + svg;
            });
    }
```

IF I simply comment out the `<foreignObject>` tag section, then the image does not show. What is the correct way of generating this svg without `<foreignObject>`

Comment: How is resulting `data URI` rendered?

Comment: the idea is to use canvas.toDataURL(). But on iOS browsers, it throws an error, "SecurityError: Dom exception 18. Process is insecure". After quite a lot of digging, I came to the conclusion that the foreignOBject tag is causing the issue. In my case, I will only have contents of same origin, I just need to get the foreignObject tag removed

Comment: Does `.toSvg` method described at documentation not return expected result? Or, does `.toSvg` method use `<foreignObject>`?

Comment: http://avarachan.com/test3.html will show how it is rendered with foreignobject tag. But it wont work on ios browsers

Comment: All methods I believe use the makeSvgDataUri() function, including toSvg

Comment: Not certain what is supposed to be rendered at link? What node are you trying to create an image of?

Comment: if you click on the yellow button, the div should convert to an image. thats the idea. Sorry lot of codes tested in the url, so if you look at the source, you will see what all i have tried.

Comment: Do not have access to ios, unable to reproduce issue, here.

Comment: yeah, i have iphone. I can test teh page. if thats what you meant.

Comment: No, cannot test here. Does `canvas.toBlob()` or `.getImageData()` throw error?

Comment: yup, I tried blob, png, jpeg, everything. All fails because ( I believe) of the foreignObject. Oh, not getImageData(). How can I do that? canvas.getImageData()?

Comment: Are you trying to render from a `canvas` or to `canvas`?

Comment: If all went well, I will use the toPng(), which will return a canvas.toDataURL. I can use that as value for an img src"". So, I am trying to get data from a canvas

Comment: See [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) , [createImageBitmap alternative on Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094245/createimagebitmap-alternative-on-safari/40095752#40095752)

Comment: ok, let me try that.

Comment: Have you tried `.toPixelData`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127413/discussion-between-avc-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known security issue introduced in safari since version 9.
Since drawing a foreignObject implies an XMLParser to be used, the risk for malicious code is huge in this area. Safari probably knows that they lack of something in here and prefer to taint the canvas.
The same applies for IE below edge with all svg images.

Since this is a security issue, there is no workaround, except using an other library that don't do hacky things like this. *Even on browsers that do support it, there is so many security restrictions applied on this technique that it won't do any good.*

The only solid way to have your html drawn on the canvas is to use solelly canvas methods to do so.
Libraries like html2canvas or others do this and won't taint your canvas.